# Access multiple mongo databases with mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb

From within a single nodejs app, how can I switch between mongodb instances?

For some context, I'm writing a queue worker with nodejs/zeromq/mongoose.

I have multiple nodejs/mongo apps running on the same server, each with their own mongo database, push jobs to a queue.

My worker app pulls and processes the jobs sequentially.

Depending which app sent the job, it needs to connect to the appropriate mongo database through mongoose. All apps use the same mongoose models, so the same models are already available in my worker app.

I'm having trouble switching connections and I'm afraid listing the details of my attempts/results would muddy up the question here.

It doesn't matter if it's limited to 1 at a time, or if I maintain a collection of connections.

Any insight would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use `createConnection`. See the docs Here: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html. I haven't done it myself, but I believe you then just create models attached to each schema

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var db = mongoose.createConnection(..);
db.model('Venue', new Schema(..));
var Ticket = db.model('Ticket', new Schema(..));
var Venue = db.model('Venue');
```